# Windows 7 network fallback from LAN to WiFi

Tags: networking, windows-7, wifi

Is it possible to make Windows 7 connect to an available WiFi network automatically **only if LAN is disconnected**? The only option I see right now is that Windows connects using both LAN and WiFi. This is undesirable because my router limits the amount of total active connections and I would like to only employ one at a time.

Comment: You could see if changing the network metric. Windows will automatically use the network connetion with the lowest metric, so see if my [answer to this question on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/234258/automatically-prefer-ethernet-over-wlan/234265#234265) would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Linux, Mac OSX, FreeBSD, etc can all do this, but Windows does not have any built-in link aggregation capability.  There may be 3rd party software that can make it work, but not just Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I know the name for this I was able to verify that indeed Windows does not support link aggregation using this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation )

Comment: Some laptops have an option in the BIOS to automatically disable the wLAN card when a LAN connection is present, mostly newer laptops. It still has the problem of disconnecting all active connections when you switch though.

Comment: My IBM thinkpad could do this 3 years ago, but it was with their connection manager.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free but it's got a 30 days trial and costs about 8$ if you decide to buy it: [Wireless AutoSwitch XPV](http://www.wirelessautoswitch.com/Home.aspx)

I don't know of any way to do it natively in Windows.